# Unknown SSL protocol error in a ftp upload with cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file with an explicit ftp over tls connection, using cURL in PHP. The authentication with the ftp server succeeds, but when i try to upload the file in passive mode, i receive the following error: "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to server.domain.nl:21".

What can be the issue in this case? Could it be that the port for the passive upload is blocked by my provider? Can i change the port for the file upload?

My website provider doesn't support ftp_ssl_connect, so i cannot use that function.

Thx,
Jack

FTP Log:

> 230 User logged in.
>   PBSZ 0
>   < 200 PBSZ command successful.
>   PROT P
>   < 200 PROT command successful.
>   PWD
>   < 257 "/" is current directory.
>   * Entry path is '/'
>   CWD avs
>   < 250 CWD command successful.
>   EPSV
>   * Connect data stream passively
>   < 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50075|)
>   *   Trying x.x.x.x...
>   * Connecting to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 50075
>   TYPE I
>   < 200 Type set to I.
>   STOR 00191_2773.xml
>   < 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
>   * Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
>   * successfully set certificate verify locations:
>   *   CAfile: c:\vevida\php54\cacert.pem
>     CApath: none
>   * SSL re-using session ID
>   * Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to server.domain.nl:21 
>   * Closing connection 19

My code is:

```
$ch = curl_init() ;

    $stderr = fopen("d:\\www\\domein.nl\\www\\pdf\\temp\\curl.txt", "w"); 
    $fp = fopen($fileLocation191, 'r') ;

    //logging:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $stderr) ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://user:pw@server.domein.nl/avs/'.$remote_file191) ;  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, TRUE) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($fileLocation191)) ;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 21) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pw');

    // SSL STUFF        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1) ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1') ;  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH) ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS) ;             
    // EINDE SSL 

    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPPORT, '-') ; 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, TRUE) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_PASV, TRUE) ;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPRT, FALSE) ;


    curl_exec ($ch) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be that the port for the passive upload is blocked by my provider?

It can be that the provider only allows few outgoing ports, but I doubt it. Ask the provider.

> Can i change the port for the file upload?

No, this port is determined by the FTP server.

Some thing you should check:

- Try it with plain FTP to find out if the problem is related to FTP over TLS.
- Try it with a different FTP server.
- Try to reach the server with a different program.

Apart from that:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false) ;
```

Why do you use TLS at all since you are disabling validation of the peer anyway? Or is this only for testing?

Comment: Thx. I will ask my provider if it allows outgoing ports. I have tried it with a different ftp server with ftp_connect() and that worked. I'll try to connect with a different server with cURL, maybe that will give me new information..